# Магические свойства __get и __set и оператор [] = , хранение массивов

Tags: php, массивы

PHP 5.6+. Имеется класс.

```
class PropertyContainer {
    protected $_data;

    public $somePublicArray = [0];

    public function __construct($data = [])
    {
        $this->_data = $data;
    }

    public function __get($name)
    {
        return array_key_exists($name, $this->_data) ? $this->_data[$name] : null;
    }

    public function __set($name, $value)
    {
        $this->_data[$name] = $value;
    }

    public function __unset($name)
    {
        unset($this->_data[$name]);
    }

    public function __isset($name)
    {
        return array_key_exists($name, $this->_data);
    }
}
```

Работа со свойствами класса происходит через магические методы и внутренний массив `$_data`, если свойство не объявлено в классе - довольно стандартный подход. И всё бы здорово, если бы не странный подход к оператору `[] =` в PHP: проводим тест

```
$cont = new PropertyContainer(['a' => 1, 'b' => [0], 'c' => new ArrayObject ([0])]);

$cont->a++; /*$cont->a = 2 OK*/
$cont->b[] = 1; /*$cont->b = [0] FAIL*/
$cont->somePublicArray[] = 1; /*$cont->somePublicArray = [0,1] OK*/
$cont->c[] = 1; /*$cont->c = ArrayObject [0,1] OK*/

var_dump($cont, is_array($cont->c));
die();
```

То есть массивы, содержащиеся внутри `$_data` возвращаются не по ссылке.

**Вопрос** - какие есть способы это обойти, и использовать оператор `[] =` для заполнения внутренних массивов, кроме как массово использовать `ArrayObject` вместо `array`? С такой же проблеммой [сталкивались](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10454779/php-indirect-modification-of-overloaded-property) , но эти решения не работают для хранения данных произвольных типов во внутреннем массиве (вроде `$_data`)- хотелось бы храннить данные в массиве (или ArrayObject) как есть.

В использовании `ArrayObject` не нравится не срабатывания метода is_array() на нём, может быть можно переопределить поведение `is_array`  ?

Если использовать `&__get` вместо `__get` - можно ли вернуть указатель на элемент массива `$_data` ? Иначе будет просто варнинг `Only variable references should be returned by reference` .

Comment: начать нужно с `class PropertyContainer implements ArrayAccess`
а дальше - [сюда](http://php.net/manual/ru/arrayaccess.offsetexists.php)

Comment: @DiGiTAL не понимаю, как `ArrayAccess`  поможет. Ведь меня устраивает доступ к объекту `PropertyContainer` через `->` . А `ArrayAccess`  даёт нам возможность переопределить доступ через квадратные скобки, а не через `->`

Comment: переопределить поведение `is_array` теоретически [возможно](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.runkit-function-redefine.php),
но чем тебя тогда не устраивает `($var instanceof ArrayObject)`?

Comment: и раз уж ты все-равно их публичными делаешь, то вообще [вот так можно](http://pastebin.com/z4pJ4MDy)

Comment: @DiGiTAL длинно. Мне это нужно для абстрактного класса - а значит этим массово будут пользоваться программисты. А гемороя и лишних думок им прибавлять не хочется) `вот так можно` - да, но тогда теряется возможность перехватывать геттеры/сеттеры.

Comment: а зачем их перехватывать, если и так все в публичном доступе?

Comment: @DiGiTAL предположим что-то надо делать при любом изменении данных. А зачем тогда вообще геттеры и сеттеры?)

Comment: для того, чтобы переопределять вызовы. т.е. если кроме как заасайнить проперти, тебе надо добавить к нему что-нибудь, ну или какое-то действие выполнить перед назначением/чтением

Comment: @DiGiTAL __get __set __isset и.т.п. вызывается в PHP только для несуществующих свойств. Соответсвенно чтобы они вызывались всегда - свойства не должны существовать в классе.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вариант 1: Если не нужна поддержка не объявляенных свойств:

```
public function &__get($name)
{
    if( array_key_exists($name, $this->_data) )
        $val = &$this->_data[$name];
    else
        $val = null;
    return $val;
}
```

В этом варианте есть баг:

```
$cont = new PropertyContainer(['a' => 1, 'b' => [0]]);
$cont->d[] = 1; // d не будет добавлено, вообще ничего не произойдёт.
```

Вариант 2: Баг первого варианта исправлен, но `_data` будет захламлятся если есть попытки получать необъявляенные свойства.

```
public function &__get($name)
{
    if( ! array_key_exists( $name, $this->_data ) ){
        $undefined; //It is possible to set default 
                    //      value for every new parameter
                    //Default is undefined.
        $this->_data[ $name ] = $undefined;
    }

    $val = &$this->_data[$name];

    return $val;
}
```

Comment: Круто, работает! Не пойму, вроде пробовал тоже самое, не работало, скопипастил код, заработало, спасибо!